# Left outer join statements containing Reference navigation properties found in all split queries

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have an entity which contains several reference navigation properties under it.

The Repository implementation for the entity looks some thing like this:

```
return await _dbContext.MyEntity
                                     .Include(s => s.Address) //Reference Navigation
                                     .Include(s => s.BuildingDetails) //Reference Navigation
                                        .ThenInclude(s => s.ChildOfBuildingDetails)
                                     .Include(s => s.ContactPersons)
                                     .Include(s => s.Technicians)
                                     .Include(s => s.DeactivationDetails)  //Reference Navigation
                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id, cancellationToken);
```

When I check the actual DB queries being executed, all the queries contain the reference navigation properties included in them as joins to the parent entity.

```
SELECT [m92].[Id], .......
FROM [MyDB].[ContactPersons] AS [m92]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [m93].[Id], [t76].[Id] AS [Id0]
    FROM [MyDB].[MyEntity] AS [m93]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [m94].*
        FROM [MyDB].[DeactivationDetails] AS [m94]
        WHERE [m94].[Deleted] = 0
    ) AS [t75] ON [m93].[Id] = [t75].[MyEntityId]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [m95].*
        FROM [MyDB].[BuildingDetails] AS [m95]
        WHERE [m95].[Deleted] = 0
    ) AS [t76] ON [m93].[Id] = [t76].[MyEntityId]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [m96].*
        FROM [MyDB].[Address] AS [m96]
        WHERE [m96].[Deleted] = 0
    ) AS [t77] ON [m93].[Id] = [t77].[MyEntityId]
    WHERE [m93].[Deleted] = 0
) AS [t78] ON [m92].[MyEntityId] = [t78].[Id]
WHERE [m92].[Deleted] = 0
ORDER BY [t78].[Id], [t78].[Id0]
```

Basically, the whole portion inside the INNER JOIN is present in all the queries that are being executed. Ideally we only need to join the child entities with parent entity in the queries.

1) Why does EF core translate to queries such that it includes the reference navigation property in all the split queries?

2) Is there a way to avoid this behavior, to be specific, replace the INNER JOIN block with just the parent entity

Comment: (1) EF Core defect (2) No, because of (1) (3) In 3.0 this would be a single query, but might be times slower due to the cartesian product of the data sets.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes you are right. We experienced the performance impact due to cartesian explosion while upgrading to .NET Core 3.1. Query execution in certain cases went from a few milliseconds to 5-6 minutes, so we had to downgrade just EF Core back to 2.2(while keeping app at .NET Core 3.1).

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why does EF core translate to queries such that it includes the reference navigation property in all the split queries?

It's an implementation defect/missing optimization.

> 2) Is there a way to avoid this behavior, to be specific, replace the INNER JOIN block with just the parent entity

The only way I found is to materialize the query with collection navigation property includes (which generate the additional queries) removed, then manually execute queries to load the related collections (requires tracking queries and relies on navigation property fix-up).

For instance (assuming navigation properties not marked as reference are collections):

```cs
// Query with filters only
var query = _dbContext.MyEntity
    .Where(s => s.Id == id);

// Execute and materialize query with only filters and reference includes
var result = await query
    .Include(s => s.Address) //Reference Navigation
    .Include(s => s.BuildingDetails) //Reference Navigation
        //.ThenInclude(s => s.ChildOfBuildingDetails)
    //.Include(s => s.ContactPersons)
    //.Include(s => s.Technicians)
    .Include(s => s.DeactivationDetails)  //Reference Navigation
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

// Load the related collections
await query.SelectMany(s => s.BuildingDetails.ChildOfBuildingDetails)
    .LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
await query.SelectMany(s => s.ContactPersons)
    .LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
await query.SelectMany(s => s.Technicians)
    .LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
```